# Significato di "torcere in male"

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *Il pugno chiuso*, di Arrigo Boito, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Costui era un antiquario russo, molto erudito e molto scaltro, uno di quelli che **torcono in male** la scienza, come altri **torcono in male** la forza.

La mia domanda è sull'espressione "torcere in male" che appare in questa frase. Non sono riuscita a trovarla su nessun dizionario,  ma ricercando "torcere in male" o "torce in male" su Google ne appaiono alcune occorrenze. Se ne trovano anche di "torcere in bene" o "torce in bene".

Delle accezioni di "torcere" che ho trovato sui dizionari, non ho saputo vedere a quale possa corrispondere l'uso che se ne fa in queste espressioni
(capisco, però, che è figurato).

Il significato sarebbe "convertire in male"? Ma perché si usa "torcere"? Ho la sensazione che mi sfugga qualche sfumatura.

Comment: @Hachi: "Stravolgere" nel senso di "trasformare qualcosa profondamente"? Non avevo pensato prima che il significato potesse essere questo perché non conoscevo questo senso figurato di "stravolgere": ho dovuto cercarlo nel dizionario.

Comment: Va bene, @Hachi: se è così, veramente mi sfuggiva qualche sfumatura: quella di "trasformazione profonda".

Comment: Forse al giorno d'oggi diremmo “storcere”, cioè “distorcere”.

Comment: @egreg: Nel senso di "modificare in peggio, alterare"?

Comment: @Charo La portano in direzione del male, sebbene sia naturalmente disposta al bene.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il verbo torcere si usa spesso per indicare un’azione di forza contro il movimento naturale di una cosa, ad esempio, come suggerisce [Treccani.it:](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/torcere/)

> *l’afferrò per la mano e gli torse il braccio per farlo andare in terra;*
>
> *torcersi le mani, una con l’altra,* come manifestazione di sconforto,
> di disperazione.

Questo significato per estensione ha assunto il significato di “stravolgere”; sempre da Treccani.it:

> Con senso affine a stravolgere: *torcere le parole, torcere il senso di uno scritto*, trarre le parole a un significato diverso.

Nel l'espressione “torcere in male la scienza” il senso sembra essere quello sopra esposto, ossia forzare la scienza verso il male, verso risultati negativi, contrariamente a quanto dovrebbe fare.